# What exactly does "closing over" mean?

Tags: functional-programming, closures, terminology

In conjunction with closures I often read that *something* **closes** over *something else* as a means to explain closures.

Now I don't have much difficulty understanding closures, but "closing over" appears to be a more fundamental concept. Otherwise one would not refer to it to explain closures, would one?

What is the exact definition of *closing over*, and what is the *something* and the *something else*? Where does the term come from?

Comment: it usually means to "add add elements to a set and then *some more*" - the *so more* part should make sure that the properties of the set remain valid - in this case it's the environments you get your values from - you add the ones, and all you might need for them, you are using inside the lambda to it - that's the closure

Answer (score 36):

Consider:

```
something closes over something else
|_______| |_________| |____________|
    |          |             |
 subject      verb        object
```

Here:

1. The subject is the closure. A closure is a function.
2. The closure “closes over” (as in encloses) the set of its free variables.
3. The object is the set of the free variables of the closure.

Consider a simple function:

```
function add(x) {
    return function closure(y) {
        return x + y;
    };
}
```

Here:

1. The function named `add` has only one variable, named `x`, which is not a free variable because it is defined within the scope of `add` itself.
2. The function named `closure` has two variables, named `x` and `y`, out of which `x` is a free variable because it is defined in the scope of `add` (not `closure`) and `y` is not a free variable because it is defined in the scope of `closure` itself.

Hence, in the second case the function named `closure` is said to “close over” the variable named `x`.

Therefore:

1. The function named `closure` is said to be a closure of the variable named `x`.
2. The variable named `x` is said to be an upvalue of the function named `closure`.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: (1) All this could be said in few words: *"A closes over B" == "B is a free variable of A", where free variables are those that appear in a function's body, but not in its signature.* (2) The answer gives no intuition about what to visualise and why the term "closes over" (and "closure") was chosen. Is it due to the semantics (does something close? or is something becoming closer?) or was the word chosen to make discussions sound more profound and mysterious?

Comment: Feel free to write your own answer.

Comment: This is all I needed (thanks!): “closes over” as in “encloses”